# Control Canon VB-C10 using HTML5 or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, webcam

Is it possible to control a webcam, in this case the `Canon VB-C10` using `HTML5` or `JavaScript`?

Currently the only plugin available that is provided by Canon is a java applet, which everyone hates, and most people want to use mobile, so it doesn't work.

There are some iOS apps out there that can interface with the camera, so there must be some ways of doing it without Java.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you find any further information about that?

Comment: @monavari-lebrecht - Yeah, I wrote a javascript plugin to control it.